# Getting table scan despite of having a covering non clustered index

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Table** :dbo.Cache

**Table Definition:**

```
create tABLE DBO.CACHE
(
Serial int identity(1,1) not null Primary Key,
StringSearched nvarchar(30),
RowId int,
ColName nvarchar(30),
PercentMatch decimal(18, 4),
createdAt datetime default getdate(),
modifiedAt datetime default getdate(),
createdBy nvarchar(128) default SUSER_NAME(),
ModifiedBy nvarchar(128) default SUSER_NAME()
)
```

**Indexes:**

```
create nonclustered index nonclustInd_Cache
            ON Cache(StringSearched, ColName) include( RowId, PercentMatch) --It is a covering index as per the query we have
create nonclustered index nonclustInd_Cache_RowId
ON Cache(RowId)
```

**Query:**

```
INSERT INTO #Temp2(RowNumber,ValFromUser,ColumnName,Percentage) SELECT RowId,StringSearched,ColName,PercentMatch FROM   dbo.Cache AS C WHERE  StringSearched = @email AND colName = 'email'
```

**Execution Plan :**

[image: Execution plan]

***With over million rows :***

[image]

**Problem:**

How do I avoid this Table scan? This table being a Cache table is going to be really huge and I can not afford to have a table scan on it.

Comment: Add more data.  The SQL Server optimizer chooses the best plan based on statistics and data involved.  For a very small table, the table scan is likely the best/easiest, and so it'll choose that.  If you add many hundreds of more rows, then it might choose a different plan.  With many thousands of more rows, it might choose a different plan again.

Comment: That said, unless the index is a complete covering index, use of an index can cause a separate lookup to find the "rest" of the data that you want. So you can either INCLUDE all the other non-indexed columns in the index itself, or declare a clustered index (where the index IS the row), depending on the data and the way it'll be queried/used.

Comment: pmbAustin : Thank you. But I tried it with over a thousand rows and made it a covering index and yet no help.

Comment: Try it with more like 50k rows.   And a WHERE clause that will only select a small percentage of them.    And if all else fails, use a query hint.

Comment: pmbAustin is 100% correct. Reading a table of under 100K row(depends on the table) is normally faster than doing a non-clustered index lookup. A 1000 rows is so tiny the server can read it super fast sequentially. Remember query plans changes over time what you have today is not there tomorrow. Database tuning is not a once of it is a continuous effort which is monitor the database for performance problems, identify performance issues , analyse the issue using query plan and performance counters, make adjustments, test adjustments, release adjustments and then start all over again.

Comment: @TabAlleman : I tried it with10Lakh rows andit is still doing a table scan. Please check the updated question. SHall I consider using FORCESEEK ?

Comment: So, you have 1M rows in a table. How many rows does your `SELECT` return? Before digging deeper: `rebuild index`; `update statistics with fullscan`; re-run your query with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`. If you still get table scan, measure the IO and time it takes to do the query as is and then compare results when you use `FORCESEEK` hint. It could turn out that `FORCESEEK` is less efficient.

Comment: On the second screenshot the server suggests to create an index. What does it suggest? Also, include the **actual** full definition of your table and indexes into the question.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov: The select statement is selecting 10% of total rows in the table.The index suggested is exactly what we have already, a covering index, the first one that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov: Updated question with table definiton and index definition are there as well.

Comment: Selecting 100K rows out of 1M could be indeed more efficient by doing full scan of the table. `SET STATISTICS IO ON`, do your query as is and with `forceseek` hint and compare logical reads.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov: With only 500 rows, it took only a second less with FORCESEEK .

Comment: This covering NCI should always be used. Selectivity does not matter here. No key lookup should be necessary. Post the actual execution plan as XML somewhere. Also, rebuild the index once to make sure the pages are full. If the index is bigger than the table (unlikely) it might not be used. (This is a rather contrived idea.) Also, could it be that you are looking at the wrong database or table?

Comment: Why is the server suggesting that you add an index that you already have?   It makes me wonder if you really have the index that you think you have.

Answer (score -1):

> try to use [forceseek](http://The%20FORCESEEK%20table%20hint%20may%20be%20useful%20when%20the%20query%20plan%20uses%20a%20table%20or%20index%20scan%20operator%20on%20a%20table%20or%20view,%20but%20an%20index%20seek%20operator%20may%20be%20more%20efficient.) FORCESEEK applies to both clustered and
>   nonclustered index seek operations. The FORCESEEK table hint may be
>   useful when the query plan uses a table or index scan operator on a
>   table or view, but an index seek operator may be more efficient.

Comment: Even if this worked it is a band-aid fix and does not address the root cause.

Comment: Using query hints like this means you cant deal with changing data and statistics there are times where a scan will be faster than a seek especially on non clustered indexes. Like I said performance tuning is not a once off effort it is a continuous cycle.

Comment: as you can see i wrote 'TRY'.Just as others have advised .Do that with FORCESEEK and compare it without .